# Very Long If Statement in Python

Tags: python

I have a very long if statement in Python. What is the best way to break it up into several lines? By best I mean most readable/common.

Comment: Show the code, please!

Answer (score 259, accepted):

According to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), long lines should be placed in parentheses. When using parentheses, the lines can be broken up without using backslashes. You should also try to put the line break *after* boolean operators.

Further to this, if you're using a code style check such as [pycodestyle](http://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes), the next logical line needs to have different indentation to your code block.

For example:

```
if (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz > some_other_long_identifier and
        here_is_another_long_identifier != and_finally_another_long_name):
    # ... your code here ...
    pass
```

Comment: Make sure to turn off `E129` or use Andrew Clark's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5253419/981933) otherwise PEP8 will throw an error at you. See: https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8/issues/126 and https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8/issues/386

Comment: Don't turn off `E129`, just comply with it. It is hard to read things without it.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to comply with `E129`. It's not happy with anything I try.

Comment: To comply with E129 add 4 more spaces before here_is_another_long_identifier [..]

The example below by Andrew Clark explains best and should be the real answer.

Comment: Just a comment on your solution the break should be before the 'and' operator. the new rule of pep8.

Comment: As it states on the PEP 8 page: "For new code Knuth’s style is suggested." which is the style with the line break before operators. It is not a 'rule' though.

Answer (score 54):

Here is the example directly from [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on limiting line length:

```
class Rectangle(Blob):

    def __init__(self, width, height,
                 color='black', emphasis=None, highlight=0):
        if (width == 0 and height == 0 and
                color == 'red' and emphasis == 'strong' or
                highlight > 100):
            raise ValueError("sorry, you lose")
        if width == 0 and height == 0 and (color == 'red' or
                                           emphasis is None):
            raise ValueError("I don't think so -- values are %s, %s" %
                             (width, height))
        Blob.__init__(self, width, height,
                      color, emphasis, highlight)
```

Comment: But this causes E129, visually indented line with the same indent as next logical line, using the pep8 lint checker.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The indentation got messed up.  Correction pending review or look directly at the example in [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Readability is damaged by putting multiple parameters on one line, but then still breaking and putting the rest on a second line. Either break after each or keep them all in one line, if it is not too long. "What's so special about `height`, that there is a break after it?" "Why not break after `width` or `color`?" These kind of questions only arise with breaking, which does not follow a strict rule.

Comment: it's still compliant if you break according to E129  and each line stays within 80 columns, which what the linter checks for. Note the non-associative operators.